# strtotime() returns 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Tags: php, strtotime

I have the following code:

```
        $d = str_replace('at', '', '08-24-2016 at 11:18 AM');
        $d = strtotime($d);
        $postdate = date('Y-d-m H:i:s',$d);
        echo $postdate;
```

It returns: `1970-01-01 00:00:00` just dates older than this. If I change it to today. It works fine. Any ideas?

Any idea how to convert that date properly?

Comment: Use `DateTime::createFromFormat` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: if you replace **-** with **/** it would work "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. "

Comment: @CharlotteDunois tried it and it doesn't work `DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:i:s A', $d);` returns nothing...

Comment: Well, because there are no seconds in your code. https://3v4l.org/ZSNjA

Comment: I'm an idiot! You're golden :) Thank you so much!